# GameLoop Thread occasionally slow

Tags: java, android, multithreading

For the game I'm currently writing for Android devices, I've got a class called RenderView, which is a Thread and updates and renders everything. Occasionally the class logs the message "Game thread is only updating the update method and is not rendering anything". The game is running at 30 fps on my nexus s. And I get the message a couple of times throughout the session. Could someone tell me how I could optimize the class or if I'm forgetting something or that it's totally normal?

Here's my code:

```
public class RenderView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    public final String classTAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    Game game;
    Bitmap framebuffer;
    Thread gameloop;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean running;

    int sleepTime;
    int numberOfFramesSkipped;
    long beginTime;
    long endTime;
    long lastTime;
    int differenceTime;
    int framePeriod;
    Canvas canvas;
    int frameCount;
    WSLog gameEngineLog;

    public RenderView(Game game, Bitmap framebuffer) {
        super(game);
        this.game = game;
        this.framebuffer = framebuffer;
        this.holder = getHolder();
        framePeriod = 1000/game.getFramesPerSecond();
        lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        gameEngineLog = game.getGameEngineLog();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running == true) {
            if(holder.getSurface().isValid()) {

                beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                numberOfFramesSkipped = 0;

                game.getCurrentScreen().update();
                game.getCurrentScreen().render(); // Draw out everything to the current virtual screen (the bitmap)
                game.getGraphics().renderFrameBuffer(); // Actually draw everything to the real screen (combine both bitmaps)

                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                if(canvas != null) { // Fix for mysterious bug ( FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread)
                    // The viewing area of our virtual screen on our real screen
                    canvas.drawBitmap(framebuffer, null, game.getWSScreen().getGameScreenextendeddst(), null);
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
                else {
                    gameEngineLog.e(classTAG, "Surface has not been created or otherwise cannot be edited");
                }

                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();;
                differenceTime = (int) (endTime - beginTime);
                sleepTime = (int) (framePeriod - differenceTime);

                if(sleepTime > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    while(sleepTime < 0 && numberOfFramesSkipped < game.getMaxFrameSkippes()) {
                        gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Game thread is only updating the update method and is not rendering anything");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5);
                        } 
                        catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                            exception.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        game.getCurrentScreen().update();
                        sleepTime += framePeriod;
                        numberOfFramesSkipped++;
                    }
                }

             // Frame Per Second Count
                frameCount++;

                if(lastTime + 1000 < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                    game.getGameEngineLog().d(classTAG, "REAL FPS: " + frameCount);
                    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    frameCount = 0;
                }

            }
        }

    }

    public void resume() { 
        running = true;
        gameloop = new Thread(this);
        gameloop.start();         
    }   

    public void pause() { 
        running = false;                        
        while(running == true) {
            try {
                gameloop.join();
                running = false;
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        gameloop = null;
    }

}
```

Here's the code for the Graphics class (the getGraphics() just return an graphics object):

```
public class Graphics {

    public final String classTAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    Game game;
    Canvas frameBuffer;
    Canvas canvasGameScreenextended;
    Canvas canvasGameScreen; // Used for customeScreen
    Bitmap gameScreenextended;
    Bitmap gameScreen;
    Rect gameScreendst;
    Rect gameScreenextendeddst;
    WSLog gameEngineLog;

    Graphics(Game game, Bitmap framebuffer, Bitmap gameScreen) {
        this.game = game;
        // Initialize canvases to render to
        frameBuffer = new Canvas(framebuffer);
        canvasGameScreen = new Canvas(gameScreen);
        // Initialize images to be rendered to our composition
        this.gameScreen = gameScreen;
        // Set up the Log
        gameEngineLog = game.getGameEngineLog();
    }

    public void resetCanvasGameScreenextended() {
        // This method has to be called each time the screen scaling type changes
        canvasGameScreenextended = new Canvas(game.getWSScreen().getGameScreenextended());
        gameScreenextended = game.getWSScreen().getGameScreenextended();
    }

    public Canvas getCanvasGameScreenextended() {
        return canvasGameScreenextended;
    }

    public Canvas getCanvasGameScreen() {
        return canvasGameScreen;
    }

    public void renderFrameBuffer() {
        // Composition
        // First layer (bottom)
        frameBuffer.drawBitmap(gameScreen, null, game.getWSScreen().getGameScreendst(), null);
        // Second layer (top)
        frameBuffer.drawBitmap(gameScreenextended, null, game.getWSScreen().getGameScreenextendeddst(), null);
    }

    public void clearFrameBuffer() {
        canvasGameScreen.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        //canvasGameScreenextended.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        gameScreenextended.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // Make top layer transparent
    }

}
```

Here's the code for the screen class (the getCurrentScreen() method returns a screen object):

```
public class Screen {

    public final String classTAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    protected final Game game;
    protected final Graphics graphics;

    protected Screen(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
        this.graphics = game.getGraphics();
        //game.getInput().reset();
    }

    public void update() {

    }

    public void render() {

    }

    /** Initialize all the sensory that should be used within this screen.*/

    public void resume() {

    }

    public void pause() {
        game.getInput().useAccelerometer(false);
        game.getInput().useKeyboard(false);
        game.getInput().useTouchscreen(false);
    }

    public void onDispose() {
        game.getGraphics().clearFrameBuffer();
    }

    public void setScreenResizeType(int screenResizeType) {

    }
```

The Screen class is extended and the render() method is shadowed with methods like:

```
graphics.getCanvasGameScreen().drawRect(play, red);
```

The funny thing is, when I override the render() method and don't place any code in it, the logger fires constantly with the message: "Game thread is only updating the update method and is not rendering anything". What kind of sorcery is this?!

Help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on `game.getCurrentScreen(), game.getGraphics(), render(), update()` and `renderFramBuffer()` methods. Better still you can post some code on these.

Comment: I've added more code. Your help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand from your updated post, there is no rendering problem actually. Instead, your code mistakenly prints that message.

This is because you check  `if(sleepTime > 0)` , so if the rendering is very fast and sleepTime is zero, you get that message. Just change it to  `if(sleepTime >= 0)`.

Comment: Could it have something to to with the way I've designed my game loop?